# Can I download Windows 7 from Microsoft?

Tags: windows, media, license, windows-activation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7)

My new computer came with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

I want to reformat and reinstall the OS.

Where can I find an installation media download at [microsoft.com](http://microsoft.com)?

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. The other question concerns a license purchased directly from Microsoft Store. See that its accepted answer does not correctly answer my question.

Comment: Did you notice the other answer to that question with direct download links to installation media?

Comment: @Shinrai That helpful answer wasn't there before.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right.  My bad. ;)

Comment: @Shinrai Posted that answer couple hours ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft don't provide a download for Windows installations unfortunately. The Vendor will probably try and charge you for a copy of the clean media or send you out their recovery CD's which will have all their bundled software (crap-ware) You may have a recovery partition on your HDD, a lot of modern PC's / Laptops do. Saves the vendor the cost of the media ;-)
Have a look on your manufacturers website for instructions for your model to re-install the OS.
Otherwise it is Legal to download a copy of Windows either directly or over torrent or borrow a friends DVD and reinstall using your product key that is on your case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, **no**. Not legally, anyway.

I think your best option is the contact the retailer you acquired the computer from and ask for physical media.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. you need to get the installation media from the computer vendor. If the computer came with Windows pre-installed then they should provide the installation media for you.

Answer (score 1):

As a consumer, you can't. However, if you have MSDN membership, you may be able to download it.